# Formatting Biquery query to ML appropriate JSON to Pass through ML Predict

Tags: json, python-2.7, google-bigquery

Using Python 2.7, I wont to pass a query from BigQuery to ML Predict which has a [specific formating](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/v1/predict-request) request.

First: Is there an easier way to go directly from the BigQuery query to JSON in the correct format so it can be passed to `requests.post()` instead of going through pandas (from what I understand pandas is still not supported for GCP Standard)?

Second: Is there a way to construct the query to go directly to a JSON format and then modify the JSON to reflect the ML Predict JSON requirments?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
#I used the bigquery to dataframe option here to view the output.
#I would like to not use pandas in the end code.
logs = log_data.execute(output_options=bq.QueryOutput.dataframe()).result()
data = logs.to_json(orient='index')
print data
```

`'{"0":{"end_time":"2018-04-19","device":"iPad","device_os":"iOS","device_os_version":"5.1.1","latency":0.150959,"megacycles":140.0,"cost":"1.3075e-08","device_brand":"Apple","device_family":"iPad","browser_version":"5.1","app":"567","ua_parse":"0"}}'`

```
#The JSON needs to be in this format according to google documentation.
#data =  {
#  'instances': [
#    {
#      'key':'',
#      'end_time': '2018-04-19',
#      'device': 'iPad',
#      'device_os': 'iOS',
#      'device_os_version': '5.1.1',
#      'latency': 0.150959,
#      'megacycles':140.0,
#      'cost':'1.3075e-08',
#      'device_brand':'Apple',
#      'device_family':'iPad',
#      'browser_version':'5.1',
#      'app':'567',
#      'ua_parse':'40.9.8'
#    }
#  ]
#}
```

So all I would need to change is the leading key `'0'` to `'instances'` and I should be all set to pass into `requests.post().

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Edit-Adding BigQuery query:

```
%%bq query --n log_data
WITH `my.table` AS (
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<end_time STRING, device STRING, device_os STRING, device_os_version STRING, latency FLOAT64, megacycles FLOAT64,
  cost STRING, device_brand STRING, device_family STRING, browser_version STRING, app STRING, ua_parse STRING>>[] instances
)
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t)
FROM `my.table` AS t
WHERE end_time >='2018-04-19'
LIMIT 1

data = log_data.execute().result()
```

Thanks to @MikhailBerlyant I have adjust my query and code to look like this:

```
%%bq query --n log_data
SELECT [TO_JSON_STRING(t)] AS instance
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS t
WHERE end_time >='2018-04-19'
LIMIT 1
```

But when I run the execute `logs = log_data.execute().result()` I get this
[image]

Which results in this error when passing into `request.post`

`TypeError: QueryResultsTable job_zfVEiPdf2W6msBlT6bBLgMusF49E is not JSON serializable`

Is there a way within execut() to just return the json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First: Is there an easier way to go directly from the BigQuery query to JSON in the correct format

See example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, type STRING>>[(1, 'abc'), (2, 'xyz')] instances
)
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t)
FROM yourTable t
```

with result is in the format you asked for:

```
{"instances":[{"id":1,"type":"abc"},{"id":2,"type":"xyz"}]}
```

Above demonstrates the query and how it will work
In you real case  - you should use something like below

```
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t)
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS t
WHERE end_time >='2018-04-19'
LIMIT 1
```

hope this helps :o)

> Update based on comments

```
SELECT [TO_JSON_STRING(t)] AS instance
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` t    
WHERE end_time >='2018-04-19'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I have added my query to the question. Does this look correct? I am getting this error `Exception: invalidQuery: Unrecognized name: end_time at [7:7]`

Comment: you are totally missing the data in your my.table - I see the schema only. rather than this  - look correct. but you need to add data. Better  - just use your real table and remove whole WIT Hstatement at all. I needed it just to demonstrate approach. amke sense?

Comment: Sorry, I may be confused. I will not know what the data looks like until the query is finished. I am going to eventually make this a function where the date will be selected by the user and passed into the query so I will not know what the data will be. Would I just use empty brackets `[]` ?

Comment: exactly, so you should use something like - SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t)
FROM `fourtopapp.daily_logs.app_logs_data_cleaned_20180419_131416` AS t
WHERE end_time >='2018-04-19'
LIMIT 1

Comment: you don't need to define schema - and explicitly set data - as I sais  -0 I did this just to demonstrate how the query will work

Comment: Great! That worked with one exception `'instance'` is missing from the json. I received this: `f0_
{"end_time":"2018-04-19","device":"0","device_os":"Other","device_os_version":"0","latency":0.520613,"megacycles":484,"cost":"4.7944e-08","Status":"200","device_brand":"0","device_family":"Other","browser_version":"0","app":"567","ua_parse":"0"}`

Comment: oh, I see - so there is no instance field in data - I thought it is  - but anyway - do you still need help in how to add this instance or you can complete it by yourself?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you do not mind. I am not really sure how to add the `'instance'` field. Also, I am assigning the result of the query like this `logs = log_data.execute().result()` which prints the json from above. So once the instance is added I need the json to look like this: `{ 'instances': [{ 'end_time': '2018-04-19', 'device': 'iPad','device_os': 'iOS','device_os_version': '5.1.1', 'latency': 0.150959, 'megacycles':140.0,'cost':'1.3075e-08', 'device_brand':'Apple', 'device_family':'iPad', 'browser_version':'5.1', 'app':'567', 'ua_parse':'40.9.8' } ]}`

Comment: I answered your question related to query - it is up to you to get use of it. i am done with this question. If you have more questions - please post new question! you cannot add more and more  - that is not how SO works. see you in next question(s) :o)

Comment: I do appreciate your help as you have gotten me closer. The title of this question is to go from BigQuery to an ML Predict appropriate JSON file. Your solution did get me the query and I am appreciative of that but currently it is still not in an ML Predict appropriate JSON as it prints as a job number and not a JSON. I feel this is still the same question so I will leave it open and hopefully someone will be able to help me to the last step. Thanks again for your help and I will upvote as your solution as it got me almost there. Best!

Comment: sure. no problem. you own it :o) - I just exhausted my options in helping here

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this in case someone has the same problem I had or at least are stuck on were to go once you have the query.

I was able to write a function that formatted the query in the way Google ML Predict wants it to be passed into requests.post(). This is most likely a horrible way to accomplish this but I could not find a direct way to go from BigQuery to ML Predict in the correct format.

```
def logs(query):
  client = gcb.Client()
  query_job = client.query(query)
  CSV_COLUMNS ='end_time,device,device_os,device_os_version,latency,megacycles,cost,device_brand,device_family,browser_version,app,ua_parse'.split(',')

  for row in query_job.result():
    var = list(row)
    l1 = dict(zip(CSV_COLUMNS,var))
    l1.update({'key':''})
    l2 = {'instances':[l1]}
  return l2
```